# How to Clone LINUX bootable USB Pen Drive in Windows environment

Tags: linux, windows, usb, clone

I have installed LINUX mint OS into USB Pen drive. Now I cannot read it using Windows. I need to clone this drive and store it for future use. Can I do this in Windows environment? Any software?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows-implementation of the unix command "dd" will do the job.

http://www.chrysocome.net/dd